# How can I search for occurences in a string with Oracle REGEXP_INSTR

Tags: sql, regex, string, oracle

I have a string like `A12345678B`

I want to be able to check if a string starts with a character, is followed by 8 digits and ends with a character.

We are trying:

```
SELECT REGEXP_INSTR('A12345678B', '[[:alpha:]]{1}[[:digit:]]{8}[[:alpha:]]{10}',1,1,1,'i') from DUAL
```

This returns :

```
11
```

We want to be able to determine that if a string does NOT start and end with a character and is not followed by 8 digits after the first character ( see sample string above ), THEN this is not the string that we are looking for .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> string starts with a character

```
^[[:alpha:]]
```

> is followed by 8 digits

```
[[:digit:]]{8}
```

> ends with a character

```
[[:alpha:]]$
```

So the complete regex would be,

```
^[[:alpha:]][[:digit:]]{8}[[:alpha:]]$
```

This `[[:alpha:]]{10}` in your regex assumes that there must be exactly 10 alphabets present after to the 8 digit number.

Answer (score 1):

```
^[a-zA-Z][0-9]{8}[a-zA-Z]$
```

Try this.Put the anchors.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `regexp_like` if you want a full string match.  For a match, use:

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('A12345678B', '^[[:alpha:]]{1}[[:digit:]]{8}[[:alpha:]]{1}$')
```

For a non-match use:

```
WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE('A12345678B', '^[[:alpha:]]{1}[[:digit:]]{8}[[:alpha:]]{1}$')
```

Note:  this assumes that you want to filter the results (which is what your question implies, not put a flag into the `select` clause.